# A current recommended way to visualize data with AngularJS and D3.js

Tags: angularjs, svg, d3.js

I develop a web application in which I need to visualize data.
I am using AngularJS for a modular design and separation of view, data and logic.
I am using D3.js to create visualizations of data with SVG elements.

Each of AngularJS and D3.js works very well, but I feel like I'm doing something wrong by using them together in such a decoupled way.

My web application consists of both HTML elements and SVG elements, both are being generated from the same data sets. And yet, I am using two different tools to create and manipulate the UI (Angular to dynamically build the interface and D3 to dynamically build the graphics).

Both the HTML and the SVG elements need to allow interaction with the user.

I'm currently wrapping my SVG graphics with Angular controllers. Inside the controller I am directly building and manipulating the SVGs with D3. When there are many interactions, animations and data changes - **this quickly becomes painfully cumbersome and tedious**.

I created [**this simple fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EyalAr/Xhjmp/38/) as a simplified example of how I currently do things.

See the `itemsGraphCtrl` controller as an example for using D3 to create graphics from within an Angular controller.

```
/* ... */
.controller("itemsGraphCtrl", function($scope, dataStore) {

    $scope.data = dataStore.data;

    var canvas = d3.select(".canvas");

    //enter:
    canvas.selectAll('circle').data($scope.data)
        .enter().append('circle')
        .attr('cx', function(d, i) {
            return i * 30 + 10;
        })
        .attr('cy', 50)
        .attr('r', 5)
        .style('fill', 'white')
        .style('stroke', 1)
        .on('click', function(d) {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                d.selected = !d.selected;
            });
        });

    function update() {
        canvas.selectAll('circle').data($scope.data)
            .style('fill', function(d) {
                return d.selected ? 'black' : 'white';
            });
    }

    $scope.$watch('data', update, true);

});
```

[image: Example]

This hardly seems like the "Angular way" to do things.

**Any suggestions / guidelines / improvements / libraries / other solutions will be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest first making your D3 charts into reusable objects, using the pattern suggested by [this article](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/) or a library like [d3.chart](http://misoproject.com/d3-chart/).

Once your D3 charts are encapsulated in their own objects, you can wrap them in directives. As you discover how your charts will interact with the rest of your application, you will start to build up an API on the chart objects themselves; for example, the chart object may trigger an event when a circle has been clicked. You can then hook into this API in your directive wrapper. This way, you can integrate your D3 objects into your Angular code, just like you would any other GUI component or plugin.

Once you have your chart, your directive may look like this:

```
  .directive('bubbleChart', function() {
    var chart = d3.charts.bubble();

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        data: '=',
        emptyMessage: '@'
      },

      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        chart.emptyMessage(scope.emptyMessage);

        scope.$watch('data', function(data) {

          d3.select(element[0])
            .datum(data)
            .call(chart);

        });
      }
    };
  })
```

You can add additional options to your `chart` object, or let users set options via attributes.

Comment: Sounds promising, I'll look into it. Thank you!